# ISupportIncrementalLoading from bottom to top

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

I have implemented `ISupportIncrementalLoading` in WinRT for incremental loading in a `ListView`, it works great.
The problem is that the new items are added to bottom of list, to see more items, I need to go down. What I need is the opposite. I would like that to see more items, I would need to go scroll up.
The list is basically a log file, the newest date must be displayed at bottom of the list, and if I want to see older records, I would need to use the scroll up.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: not quite sure I understand, are you saying when records are incrementally loaded you want the list to be automatically scrolled to the bottom?

Comment: ISupportIncrementalLoading loads incrementally the records adding at bottom part of the ListView, then, if I want to see more records, I need to use the scroll down of ListView control. What I need is that the loaded records are added at top of ListView, not bottom. So, I want to load more records, I would need to use the scroll up of the ListView.
It must work like OutLook, when I open my app, I want to show the most recent emails, the most recent is in the bottom part of the ListView. If I want to see older emails, I would need to use the scroll up control.

Comment: This makes complete sense Dabiel.  All messaging apps are like this, where the latest message is at the bottom.  Open any text messaging app.  There would be another way to do it, but there is a problem with ListView popping in a new item at the top of the list. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30292690/win10-app-animating-in-a-new-item-at-top-of-list

Answer (score 7):

I know, the Question is old, but I had the same problem and didn't find a good solution.

So I will post my solution for other, who have the same problem.

My first solution was my own IncrementalLoadCollection with custom behaviors for scrolling and loading the data. 
It work OK, but not well enougth for me.

So I tried another powerfull XAML trick and it works perfectly, except one little mouse wheel behavior. It's reversed now :).

Solution is very simple and powerfull. Just rotate the ScrollViewer of the ListView with 180° and flipp it to have the scrollbar on the right again. Then do the same for the Items so they are correct again.

That's it. Incremental loading is handled by ListView, touch events and scrollbar works correct, just the mouse wheel behavior is reversed now.

My code

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ChatListView" ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ItemsSource}" 
                              SelectionMode="None"
                              IsItemClickEnabled="False"
                              IsZoomedInView="False"
                            ShowsScrollingPlaceholders="False"
                            VerticalContentAlignment="Top" 
                              VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                              Margin="10,5">
                        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                                            <ContentPresenter/>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <ListView.ItemContainerTransitions>
                            <TransitionCollection/>
                        </ListView.ItemContainerTransitions>
                        <ListView.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                    <ScrollViewer ZoomMode="Disabled" x:Name="ScrollViewer" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                                        <ScrollViewer.RenderTransform>
                                            <CompositeTransform Rotation="180" ScaleX="-1"/>
                                        </ScrollViewer.RenderTransform>
                                        <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter"/>
                                    </ScrollViewer>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </ListView.Template>
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <controls:ChatMessageControl Message="{Binding Message}"
                                                             ChatFrom="{Binding Name}"
                                                             IsMy="{Binding IsMy}"
                                                             ShortTime="{Binding CreatedTime}"
                                                             RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">

                                    <controls:ChatMessageControl.RenderTransform>
                                        <CompositeTransform Rotation="180" ScaleX="-1"/>
                                    </controls:ChatMessageControl.RenderTransform>
                                </controls:ChatMessageControl>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
```

Comment: Thanks your a life saver!  I tried going another avenue with checking scroll offset & using <ItemsStackPanel ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepItemsInView" /> but in the end I came up with a buggy solution that worked about 90% of the time.  I'm making a WP app so this solution is just fine b/c no mouse!

Comment: Did you try overriding OnMouseWheelChanged to invert the values?

Comment: Yes, I tried. It's long ago, but I think the problem was, that ScrollViewer handle MouseWheel event internaly and you dont have any chance to manipulate this. 

Another idee was to hide scrollbars and to create second scrollbar/scrollviewer outside and synchronize invert position. This should work, but I didnt tried it yet.

Comment: That worked for me aswell, but the mousewheel is a mayor problem for me. Did anyone find a proper solution for this? I can't get the synchronization working.

Comment: Thank you! I was stuck with this issue for a long time

Answer (score 2):

Reffering to Demetrius Axenowski answer, this is my approach to reverse the mousewheel input.

**NOTE** i'm using this for a desktop-only App

**1)** Find the first Grid inside the ScrollViewer of the ListView and hook the PointerWheelChanged event.

```
        this._ScrollViewer = this.GetChildren<ScrollViewer>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (this._ScrollViewer == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("ScrollViewer not found.");
        }

        this._ScrollViewerInsetBorder = this.GetChildren<Border>().FirstOrDefault();

        this._BorderInsetGrid = this.GetChildren<Grid>().FirstOrDefault();
        this._BorderInsetGrid.AddHandler(ScrollViewer.PointerWheelChangedEvent, new PointerEventHandler(this.SW_Handler_OnPointerWheelChanged), true);
```

**2)** Override Mousewheel behavior.

```
    double desiredVerticalOffset = 0;
    private void SW_Handler_OnPointerWheelChanged(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PointerPoint mousePosition = e.GetCurrentPoint(sender as UIElement);
        var delta = mousePosition.Properties.MouseWheelDelta;

        // calculate desiredOffset
        desiredVerticalOffset = desiredVerticalOffset + delta;

        // limit desiredOffset.
        desiredVerticalOffset = desiredVerticalOffset < 0 ? 0 : desiredVerticalOffset;
        desiredVerticalOffset = desiredVerticalOffset > _ScrollViewer.ScrollableHeight ? _ScrollViewer.ScrollableHeight : desiredVerticalOffset;

        if (delta < 0 || delta > 0)
        {
            _ScrollViewer.ChangeView(null, desiredVerticalOffset, null, false);
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```