# Incremental loading WinRT: load new items on scroll to top

Tags: listview, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I want to use incremental loading with ListView, but i want to load new items when i scroll to top. We used ISupportIncrementalLoading but new items were loaded when we scrolled to bottom of ListView. It must looks like loading chat history in Skype. How i can change orientation of scrolling?

Comment: There is a related question here, but the solution may not be ideal for you (mouse wheel behavior is broken): [ISupportIncrementalLoading from bottom to top](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14534796/isupportincrementalloading-from-bottom-to-top)